# Is the trial version of SharePoint server 2016 is full version?

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-server

I have installed SharePoint 2016 on-premise with trial serial.

When I try to integrate it with Laserfiche ECM, I get below error:

```
Troubleshoot Microsoft SharePoint Foundation issues.
Correlation ID: 4f81319f-9779-d054-0000-050eece9d13e
```

I think that it is because I am using a trial version. Can you tell me if the trial version is a full version or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trial version is the full version with a trial (time bombed) license key. You'll want to contact the vendor to troubleshoot as to why the install of Laserfiche ECM is failing.